# Mongoengine reference another document's field

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
class Doc1:
    fieldd1 = StringField()

class Doc2:
    fieldd2 = ReferenceField(Doc1.fieldd1)
```

Or should I just reference the Doc and then get the field information whenever I need it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This not posible and it is reference to document. To get `fieldd1` you must do:

```
class Doc1(Document):
    fieldd1 = StringField()

class Doc2(Document):
    fieldd2 = ReferenceField(Doc1)

Doc2.objects.first().fieldd2.fieldd1
```

If you want just include document to another as part of one document then look at `EmbeddedDocument` and `EmbeddedDcoumentField`:

```
class Doc1(EmbeddedDocument):
    fieldd1 = StringField()

class Doc2(Document):
    fieldd2 = EmbeddedDcoumentField(Doc1)

Doc2.objects.first().fieldd2.fieldd1
```

But you always can set own properties:

```
class Doc1(Document):
    fieldd1 = StringField()

class Doc2(Document):
    fieldd2 = ReferenceField(Doc1)

    @property
    def fieldd1(self):
        return self.fieldd2.fieldd1

Doc2.objects.first().fieldd1
```

See documentation: https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html.