# How to define reference field in model

Tags: django, django-mongodb-engine

I just installed the Django MongoDB Engine as explained [here](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html) and would like to define a ReferenceField in my model like people did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433971/mongoengine-reference-another-documents-field) using mongoengine.

However I can't fine how to define a document reference field using [mongoDB-engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I already thought about using EmbeddedModelFields, but the model to be referenced has quite some meaning for itself, so embedding it makes no sense for me.

I understand that the documentation of Django mongoDB engine is still in development, so I thought maybe one knows some undocumented feature.